# Android only allows one navigation page on screen at a time using

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

what is the difference between 2 implementations below?

```
 public App()
    {
        // The root page of your application
        MainPage = new Views.MainPage();
    }   
 public App()
    {     
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
    }
```

if my main page inherits MasterDetailPage, 1st code above will work but 2nd one will return error message telling me that "android only allows one navigation page on screen at a time" when I debug my android app.

```
  public class MainPage : MasterDetailPage
    {

        MasterPage masterPage;
        public MainPage()
        {
            masterPage = new MasterPage();
            Master = masterPage;
            Detail = new NavigationPage(new AnotherPage());
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I might be a bit confused by what you are asking but if you are doing

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
```

And your MainPage is

```
public class MainPage : MasterDetailPage
{

    MasterPage masterPage;
    public MainPage()
    {
        masterPage = new MasterPage();
        Master = masterPage;
        Detail = new NavigationPage(new AnotherPage());
```

Then you are doing

NavigationPage > MasterDetailPage > NavigationPage

Either MasterDetail or Navigation should be the root and not have them inside each other. You can't have 2 navigation pages within each other.

Comment: you understood correct. first i had implemented like that and i was getting this error message. I fixed after I changed to MainPage = new Views.MainPage(); which is actually redirecting to same contentpage but I didnt understand what is the difference. eventually both are doing navigation to MainPage or not?

Comment: You can have a navigation page as the Detail in a MasterDetail or you can have MasterDetail inside a Navigation Page, but you can't have a navigation page inside a navigation page at any level. This is an Android only restriction but makes it a Xamarin Forms restriction in the end.

Comment: thanks for explaining. it is clear this now but what does this mean?   MainPage = new Views.MainPage(); 
I guess app.css is like app.xaml in WPF, right? if it is yes, isn't that mean a navigation to MainPage as well?

Comment: The MainPage is the root page of the app. You can place a NavigationPage or MasterDetailPage or ContentPage there. There is no NavigationPage unless you put one in there. With Views.MainPage I think you are putting a MasterDetailPage there and it has a NavigationPage in its Detail section which is fine.