# Xamarin.Forms implement Android ActionBar

Tags: android-actionbar, xamarin.forms, navigationbar, tabbedpage

I'm working with Xamarin.Forms and I would like to create a tabbed navigation (like the one with `ActionBar` in Android) just like the one used in Google Play Store and Google Play Music (also used in the Facebook app and other modern updated apps). Here is an image with two samples. One for Play Music and the other for Play Store.

[Play Music and Play Store Tabbed Navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7e4y.jpg)

I've tried several ways of implementing this and have been through the Xamarin Cross-Platform documentation. Yet, I haven't found a clear response to this. A similar question was asked here on SO but didn't really help either.

Here is what I've tried from a sample on GitHub: [My Tabbed Nav](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvpR7.png)

But it keeps crashing with this error (and then requests for an "ActionBar.cs" file):

> **System.Exception: Android only allows one navigation page on screen at a time**

So, how on earth do I achieve this?

Now, I know it's possible. But being a newbie to Xamarin, XAML and all of it I'm having serious issues here and there of which this is one of the most crucial!

PS: Btw sorry, I'm limited to posting images and links

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try TabbedPage
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/navigation/tabbed-page/

And for impelmenting Material Design:
https://blog.xamarin.com/material-design-for-your-xamarin-forms-android-apps/

Comment: That is exactly the documentary I used but it keeps returning the 'System.Exception' error. I have gone through the Droid, iOS and Win solutions to see if I was missing something, but I wasn't.

Comment: @ChrisIdakwo please examine if you have more than one NavigationPage, like this [linke](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34406620/android-only-allows-one-navigation-page-on-screen-at-a-time-using)

Comment: Alright, I've  had a look at it & will implement it later today. I really hope that'll fix the issue. Thanks

Comment: Whoops! Whoops! It works! Oh my, you have no idea how great this is. Although, I feel kind of stupid that just such little change has held me back for a week. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@Bonelol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3172318/bonelol), I found the very simple solution to this issue here: [Android only allows one navigation page on screen at a time using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34406620/android-only-allows-one-navigation-page-on-screen-at-a-time-using)