# Android only allows one navigation page - Xamarin Forms

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

Hi I created the application using Xamarin.Forms - Its working fine in iOS but Certainly Its not working in Android and facing some issues mentioned in the title.

Lemme explain my application and code continues, The application having one login screen and will move on to home screen called HomeController using navigation in this just populating list view and its cell. While tapping each row will move on to Master detail page in this I'm getting error and it's working fine in iOS not Android.

> App.cs

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace eMO_Xamarin
{
public class App : Application
{
public App ()
{
// The root page of your application

var nav = new NavigationPage (new LoginViewController ());
nav.BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#EEEEEE");
nav.BarTextColor = Color.FromHex("#424242");

MainPage = nav;
}

}
}
```

> LoginController.cs

```
using System;

using Xamarin.Forms;

using System.Collections.Generic;


namespace eMO_Xamarin
{
public class LoginViewController : ContentPage
{

Entry userEntry, passwordEntry;

public LoginViewController ()
{

NavigationPage.SetBackButtonTitle (this, "");
NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton (this, false);
this.BackgroundImage = "Bg1.jpg";

userEntry = new Entry () {

HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
Placeholder = "Username"
};

passwordEntry = new Entry () {

HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
Placeholder = "Password",
IsPassword = true
};

var loginButton = new Button () {

Text = "Login",
TextColor = Color.White,
BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex ("77D065")

};
loginButton.Clicked += OnButtonClickedLogin;

Title = "e-Loan";

this.Padding = new Thickness (50, Device.OnPlatform (20, 0, 0), 50, 20);

stack.Children.Add (appLogoImg);
stack.Children.Add (userEntry);
stack.Children.Add (passwordEntry);
stack.Children.Add (loginButton);

this.Content = scroll;

}


void OnButtonClickedLogin (object sender, EventArgs e)
{

Navigation.InsertPageBefore (new HomeViewController (), this);
Navigation.PopAsync ();

}

}
}
```

> HomeController.cs

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using Xamarin.Forms;


namespace eMO_Xamarin
{
    public class HomeViewController : ContentPage
    {
        public HomeViewController ()
        {

            Title = "Welcome John!";

            NavigationPage.SetBackButtonTitle (this, "Back");
            NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton (this, false);

            if (Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Phone) {

                this.BackgroundImage = "login_home.jpg";

            } else if (Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Tablet) {

                this.BackgroundImage = "Bg6.jpg";

            } else {

            }

            var toolbarItem = new ToolbarItem {
                Text = "Logout"
            };
            toolbarItem.Clicked += OnLogoutButtonClicked;
            ToolbarItems.Add (toolbarItem);

            Label header = new Label {
                Text = "Submitted Loans",
                TextColor = Color.Gray,
                FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold,
                FontSize = 30,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
            };

            // Create a data template from the type ImageCell
            var cell = new DataTemplate (typeof(MenuCell));

            ListView listView = new ListView {

                ItemsSource = VetData.GetData (),
                ItemTemplate = cell, // Set the ImageCell to the item template for the listview
                //SeparatorColor = Color.Transparent

            };

            listView.RowHeight = 75;
            listView.BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent;

            // Push the list view down below the status bar on iOS.
            if (Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Phone) {

                Padding = new Thickness (10, Device.OnPlatform (20, 0, 0), 0, 0);

            } else if (Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Tablet) {

                Padding = new Thickness (150, Device.OnPlatform (50, 0, 0), 150, 10);

            } else {

            }

            // Set the content for the page.

            this.Content = new StackLayout {

                Spacing = 20,

                Children = {
                    header,
                    listView
                }
            };

            listView.ItemSelected += async (sender, e) => {


                if (e.SelectedItem != null) {
                    //do what you want with the selectedItem
                    // Navigation with back push
                    await Navigation.PushAsync (new LeadViewController ());

                }

                //then init the selectedItem of the listview to enable it to be selected again
                listView.SelectedItem = null;
            };

        }

        async void OnLogoutButtonClicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Navigation with out back push
            Navigation.InsertPageBefore (new LoginViewController (), this);
            await Navigation.PopAsync ();
        }


    }
}
```

> LeadViewController.cs : MasterDetailScreen : Error facing Screen

```
using System;

    using System.Collections.Generic;

    using Xamarin.Forms;

    namespace eMO_Xamarin
    {
        public class LeadViewController : MasterDetailPage
        {
            public LeadViewController ()
            {
                this.BackgroundImage = "Bg6.jpg";

                var menuPage = new MenuPage ();
                menuPage.OnMenuSelect = (categoryPage) => {

                Detail = new NavigationPage (categoryPage);

                    if (Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Phone) {

                        IsPresented = false;

                    } else if (Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Tablet) {

                        IsPresented = true;

                    } else {

                        IsPresented = true;
                    }
                };

                Master = menuPage;

                Detail = new NavigationPage (new LetsGetStartedPage ());

                MasterBehavior = MasterBehavior.Default;

            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Please lemme know guys why I'm facing issues in android but not for iOS. How to reproduce this issues.

Comment: can you show some error log?

Comment: I will try the below code as @Jay mentioned, If it's not helped I will send some error log -Mike Thanks. Actually I updated the Xamarin Studio Its required Xcode 8.2, So I couldn't able to build the app , So that got delayed.

Answer (score 1):

Your root page is Navigation Page. And you added a MasterDetial Page with Navigation page too.

[The similar issue here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34406620/android-only-allows-one-navigation-page-on-screen-at-a-time-using)

> Either MasterDetail or Navigation should be the root and not have them inside each other. You can't have 2 navigation pages within each othe
>
> **You can have a navigation page as the Detail in a MasterDetail or you can have MasterDetail inside a Navigation Page, but you can't have a navigation page inside a navigation page at any level. This is an Android only restriction but makes it a Xamarin Forms restriction in the end.**

Here is your error code:

`Detail = new NavigationPage (new LetsGetStartedPage ());`

I think you can try the following code:

`Detail = new LetsGetStartedPage ();`

**OR**

```
namespace eMO_Xamarin
{
   public class App : Application
   {
      public App ()
      {
         var nav = new LoginViewController ();
         nav.BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#EEEEEE");
         nav.BarTextColor = Color.FromHex("#424242");    
         MainPage = nav;
      }

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this code :**

```
listView.ItemSelected += async (sender, e) => {
    if (e.SelectedItem != null) {
        //do what you want with the selectedItem
        // Navigation with back push
        await Navigation.PushAsync (new NavigationPage(new LeadViewController ()));
    }
    //then init the selectedItem of the listview to enable it to be selected again
    listView.SelectedItem = null;
};
```

Answer (score -2):

please make sure that your App.cs has only setting page like this
        **MainPage = new MasterTestPage();**
do not set like this
        **new NavigationPage(new MasterTestPage());**
where MasterTestPage is my MasterDetailPage class

Comment: This just rephrases the other answer but with less detail